# How to return specific status code (for example 24) in symfony

Tags: php, http, symfony1, http-headers

i need to return crazy http code statuses for API in symfony

i need to return status code 24 i try to do it with:

```
$this->getResponse()->setStatusCode('24');
```

but i'm always getting response code 500

when i try to return "normal" status code like 404, 403:

```
$this->getResponse()->setStatusCode('403');
```

it has no problem

any ideas why?

Answer (score 7):

024 is an **invalid** HTTP code (this is different from "undefined"). Valid HTTP codes are in the range 100-599.

Answer (score 4):

I see this question is tagged with [symfony1](/questions/tagged/symfony1), however my answer was tested on Symfony 2.8. A similar solution is likely possible with Symfony 1.X.

---

When setting a response's status code with `$response->setStatusCode()`, Symfony preforms a [check to confirm](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php#L1035) that the provided status code is valid according to [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) - specifically, that it is between 100 - 600:

```
public function isInvalid()
{
    return $this->statusCode < 100 || $this->statusCode >= 600;
}
```

As other answers have stated, 24 is out of this range and an [exception will be thrown as a result](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php#L455). By using this status code you are not complying with HTTP standards and any normal client might not function as expected. That said, **I'm not here to judge your experiment** and a solution is available.

You can create a subclass of `Response` where you override `isInvalid()` to always return false, thus allowing any and all status codes to be set.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class NewResponse extends Response
{
    public function isInvalid()
    {
        //Accept anything.
        return false;
    }
}
```

Use this class instead of grabbing a standard `Response`:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $response = new NewResponse();
    $response->setStatusCode(24);

    return $response;
}
```

Results in getting the status code you're after:

```
$ curl -I 127.0.0.1:8000
HTTP/1.1 24 unknown status
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.10
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Debug-Token: 189e2d
X-Debug-Token-Link: /_profiler/189e2d
Date: Fri, 29 Jan 2016 22:23:29 GMT
```

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution, it has to have 3 digits

```
$this->getResponse()->setStatusCode('024');
```

similarly in header function

```
header('HTTP/1.0 024');
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be there is no 
[official status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)
 of 24.

Symfony may internally check that.

To get around it, you could do...

```
header('HTTP/1.0 24');
```